# Google chrome extensions for managing Downloads

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create an extension which puts all the pdf files downloaded by user through browser into a separate directory. Any Api by which can do this or some help on how I can do  it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot easily write to an arbitrary path, you can redirect all PDF files into a subfolder of Downloads folder.

Check out [`onDeterminingFilename` event of `chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename) and [Filename Controller sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/downloads/download_filename_controller.zip). Since you can indicate a relative path instead of a plain filename, this should work.

Note that the file's MIME type should be available in `onDeterminingFilename`, you can use that.

---

Code example, as requested:

```js
var folder = "PDF_downloads";

chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener( 
  function (item, suggest) {
    if(isPDF(item)) suggest({filename: folder + "/" + item.filename});
    else suggest();
  }
);

function isPDF(item){
  if(item.mime === "application/pdf") return true;
  else if (item.filename.match(/\.pdf$/i)) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

This will not override that the browser tries to open the PDF itself instead of downloading, but attempting to download will suggest that folder.

Comment: @cooljohny Like I said, one option is examining `downloadItem.mime`, another is observing the suggested filename for `.pdf` extension. I'd say if either of those matches, it's trying to download a PDF.

Comment: I am very new to this, if you could provide some snippet of code..that would be very helpful!!!

Comment: @cooljohny I have edited my answer to provide sample code, but please hold your horses. You are supposed to try things on your own and describe what didn't work - SO will not generally write code for you. Break down your problem into single-issue-questions.